# ¿Donde puedo desplegar servicio restfull hecho con spring boot, maven y base de datos que sea gratis ya que solo lo quiero para pruebas?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, cors

Una consulta donde puedo desplegar mi proyecto spring boot maven ya que he tenido problemas en el despliegue en render , debido a que me manda problemas de cors, pero en mi local me funciona de bien.

Comment: Te aviso que no damos recomendaciones de recursos externos. Sin embargo, podrías preguntar en otro lado o editar la publicación para preguntar respecto al error en render